# How can I store emails on an external drive with Postfix/Dovecot?

Tags: raspberry-pi, email, postfix, dovecot

So I set up a a Postfix/Dovecot server on my Raspberry Pi, and I wanted to be able to actually store the emails themselves I have on an external SSD I have since my SD card is 32 GBs and my SSD is half a terabyte. I know in theory I could potentially symlink `/var/mail` (or `/var/spool/mail` for some cases), but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this. Perhaps a config in either Postfix or Dovecot or some system variable I could use?

Answer (score 0):

A symlink is probably the best way to do this, especially if you use other programs that expect mail to be in `/var/mail`.

It is easy to do, self-documenting (at least to those with some familiarity with unix/linux), and - most importantly - has a minimal risk of unwanted side-effects.

While there are sometimes good reasons for changing a well-known/"standard" location, it comes at the price of having to reconfigure or recompile **everything else** that relies on that well-known location.

---

Another option would be to mount another filesystem (partition, LV, btrfs sub-volume, ZFS dataset, whatever) on `/var/mail`.

IMO & IME, this carries more risk than using a symlink.  If a symlink points to a missing directory, then postfix will just fail to deliver and keep the undelivered messages in its own queue.

OTOH, if the other fs failed to mount for some reason (e.g. the drive taking longer than expected to initialise on a cold boot), then postfix **will** deliver the mail to the `/var/mail/` sub-directory on the `/` filesystem (or `/var` if `/var` is a separate mount), leaving you with the problem of merging mailboxes split across two different filesystems (and, from personal experience, I can say that **will** be a major PITA).